# How to use audioConverterFillComplexBuffer and its callback?

Tags: macos, core-audio

I need a step by step walkthrough on how to use audioConverterFillComplexBuffer and its callback. No, don't tell me to read the Apple docs. I do everything they say and the conversion always fails. No, don't tell me to go look for examples of audioConverterFillComplexBuffer and its callback in use - I've duplicated about a dozen such examples both line for line and modified and the conversion always fails. No, there isn't any problem with the input data. No, it isn't an endian issue. No, the problem isn't my version of OS X.

The problem is that I don't understand how audioConverterFillComplexBuffer works, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  And nothing out there is *helping* me understand, because it seems like nobody on Earth really understands how audioConverterFillComplexBuffer works, either. From the people who actually use it(I spy cargo cult programming in their code) to even the authors of Learning Core Audio and/or Apple itself(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604612/core-audio-how-can-one-packet-one-byte-when-clearly-one-packet-4-bytes).

This isn't just a problem for me, it's a problem for anybody who wants to program high-performance audio on the Mac platform. Threadbare documentation that's apparently wrong and examples that don't work are no fun.

Once again, to be clear: I NEED A STEP BY STEP WALKTHROUGH ON HOW TO USE audioConverterFillComplexBuffer plus its callback and so does the entire Mac developer community.

Comment: What format are you trying to convert to?  If it's PCM your life will be simpler because no packet table is required.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. You don't want examples, you don't want docs, and you proclaim that "nobody on Earth" understands this function - yet you want someone that does understand this function to explain it. So only someone off this Earth would quality, and I really doubt people on the ISS will be visiting StackOverflow explaining Core Audio :-) And if the entire dev community needs more explanation than it already has, then only Apple can help. It's not realistic to expect an Apple engineer working on Core Audio to stumble upon this question, right? :-)

Comment: First of all, are you converting to/from compressed formats? AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer is for converting compressed formats. Secondly, I know you said you read the docs. But the documentation is pretty clear on the arguments for AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer. What is your exact question about it? Thirdly, please show us the code you have so far so we can help!

Comment: I feel your pain. Wanted to add that [this](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudio/audio_toolbox/chapter_4_section_3.html), [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/audiostreambasicdescription), [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audioconvertercomplexinputdataproc?language=objc), and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/audiobufferlist) seems to be the way, but I got stuck at error code -50 on `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` trying to deinterleave. I gave up.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question but I think is still relevant. I've spent a few days fighting this and have finally achieved a successful conversion. I'm certainly no expert but I'll outline my understanding of how it works. Note I'm using Swift, which I'm also just learning.

Here are the main function arguments:

`inAudioConverter: AudioConverterRef`: This one is simple enough, just pass in a previously created AudioConverterRef.

`inInputDataProc: AudioConverterComplexInputDataProc`: The very complex callback. We'll come back to this.

`inInputDataProcUserData, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`: This is a reference to whatever data you may need to be provided to the callback function. Important because even in swift the callback can't inherit context. E.g. you may need to access an AudioFileID or keep track of the number of packets read so far.

`ioOutputDataPacketSize: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>`: This one is a little misleading. The name implies it's the packet size but reading the documentation we learn it's the total number of packets expected for the output format. You can calculate this as `outPacketCount = frameCount / outStreamDescription.mFramesPerPacket`.

`outOutputData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>`: This is an audio buffer list which you need to have already initialized with enough space to hold the expected output data. The size can be calculated as `byteSize = outPacketCount * outMaxPacketSize`.

`outPacketDescription: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?`: This is optional. If you need packet descriptions, pass in a block of memory the size of `outPacketCount * sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription)`.

---

As the converter runs it will repeatedly call the callback function to request more data to convert. The main job of the callback is simply to read the requested number packets from the source data. The converter will then convert the packets to the output format and fill the output buffer. Here are the arguments for the callback:

`inAudioConverter: AudioConverterRef`: The audio converter again. You probably won't need to use this.

`ioNumberDataPackets: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>`: The number of packets to read. After reading, you must set this to the number of packets actually read (which may be less than the number requested if we reached the end).

`ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>`: An AudioBufferList which is already configured except for the actual data. You need to initialise ioData.mBuffers.mData with enough capacity to hold the expected number of packets, i.e. `ioNumberDataPackets * inMaxPacketSize`. Set the value of ioData.mBuffers.mDataByteSize to match.

`outDataPacketDescription: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?>?`: Depending on the formats used, the converter may need to keep track of packet descriptions. You need to initialise this with enough capacity to hold the expected number of packet descriptions.

`inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`: The user data that you provided to the converter.

---

So, to start you need to:

1. Have sufficient information about your input and output data, namely the number of frames and maximum packet sizes.
2. Initialise an AudioBufferList with sufficient capacity to hold the output data.
3. Call `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`.

And on each run of the callback you need to:

1. Initialise `ioData` with sufficient capacity to store `ioNumberDataPackets` of source data.
2. Initialise `outDataPacketDescription` with sufficient capacity to store `ioNumberDataPackets` of AudioStreamPacketDescriptions.
3. Fill the buffer with source packets.
4. Write the packet descriptions.
5. Set `ioNumberDataPackets` to the number of packets actually read.
6. return `noErr` if successful.

Here's an example where I read the data from an AudioFileID:

```swift
var converter: AudioConverterRef?
// User data holds an AudioFileID, input max packet size, and a count of packets read
var uData = (fRef, maxPacketSize, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int64>.allocate(capacity: 1))
err = AudioConverterNew(&inStreamDesc, &outStreamDesc, &converter)
err = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(converter!, { _, ioNumberDataPackets, ioData, outDataPacketDescription, inUserData in
    let uData = inUserData!.load(as: (AudioFileID, UInt32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int64>).self)
    ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mDataByteSize = uData.1
    ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mData = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: Int(uData.1), alignment: 1)
    outDataPacketDescription?.pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>.allocate(capacity: Int(ioNumberDataPackets.pointee))
    let err = AudioFileReadPacketData(uData.0, false, &ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mDataByteSize, outDataPacketDescription?.pointee, uData.2.pointee, ioNumberDataPackets, ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mData)
    uData.2.pointee += Int64(ioNumberDataPackets.pointee)
    return err
}, &uData, &numPackets, &bufferList, nil)
```

Again, I'm no expert, this is just what I've learned by trial and error.